# How to bring $\log(y) = \log(a) + \log(e^{bx})$ to $y=mx+c$ format?

Tags: logarithms, slope

I was solving a problem regarding equation of the straight line. The question is to find the best value of $a$ and $b$ if

$$ y = ae^{bx}. $$

**What I tried?**

I multiplied LHS and RHS with $\log$ in order to separate $a$ and $b$ and as a result I got the below equation.

$$ \log(y) = \log(a) + \log(e^{bx}).$$

But I am stuck.

how should I proceed to convert this equation to $y=mx+c$ format. Any help and guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [Please use MathJax.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34067)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
y &= ae^{bx}\\
\implies \ln(y) &=\ln(ae^{bx})\\
\implies \ln(y) &=\ln(a) + \ln(e^{bx})\\
\implies \ln(y) &= \ln(a) + bx\\
\implies \color{green}{\ln(y)} &= \color{blue}{b}x + \color{red}{\ln(a)}\\
\implies \color{green}{Y} &= \color{blue}mx + \color{red}{C}
\end{align}

Comment: Forgot about ln!!! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

you are so close.

$$
y = a\mathrm{e}^{bx}
$$
taking logs have you have done
$$
\log(y) = \log\left(a\mathrm{e}^{bx}\right) = \log(a) + \log\left(\mathrm{e}^{bx}\right) = \log(a) + bx
$$
you did not apply the `log` fully on the exponential

Now you can relabel
$$
\log(y) \to y'\\
\log(a) \to c
$$
we now have
$$
y' = bx + c
$$
which we now have the form you desire.

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation.